# How to trap keyboard event in Android service class?

Tags: android, keyboard-events

How to trap keyboard event in Android service class?

Answer (score 0):

No, except for the Camera KeyEvent you cannot capture key events in background threads. Only foreground activities can do so. This is the correct behavior otherwise rogue apps can get away with stealing passwords and stuff.

Comment: thanks Reno actually was trying to make that keylogger to capture events thanks for the help really wasted time on that

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);                
}
```